# Uploading a chunk of a file

Tags: php, python, file-upload, upload

In my PHP web page, I allow my clients to upload a file. That file can be very large (1-2 GB). I already modified the php.ini in order to allow the users to upload big files.

Now, I want to know how to upload only 1 chunk of the file (the size of the chunk is selected by the user). For example, I have a 1 GB file, but I only want to upload the first 150 MB of that file (the file will still work even it has been chunked, but it will have less samples to work with).

How can I do that? If I do so, I will let the user not to have to wait much time uploading the 1 GB file, and the user will upload a 150 MB file instead (150/1000 MB).

I've found some ways to do it, like PLUPLOAD, but I prefer not to use JavaScript because I want to do all the process/job in my server and not in the client's side. Or with fread(), fopen() and fwrite(), but in this case, I can't use these commands without having uploaded the full file first.

P.D.: I can also use Python to chunk the file before uploading it, if it's necessary, but I think that I'll have the same problem as fread(), fopen(), etc...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not willing to split up the file on the client before uploading it, you'll need to use some client-side code (on a supported browser) to perform partial uploads.

For an example, see https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. Well, if there is no choice, I'll have to use a client-side code to chunk the file before sending it. But I would like an option with sockets and fread() or something, that would allow the user to chunk the file without any charge in his machine.